# Does this wear pattern on my shorts indicate an issue with my position on my road bike?

Tags: saddle, clothes, riding-position, shorts

[image]

My last three pairs of bib shorts have all worn out in exactly the same place (see picture). The latest pair started wearing after about 5 rides. I average about 100 miles a week. Do you think my position is off? I feel like my sit bones are in the right place on the saddle when I'm riding and I don't have any discomfort. I've had a bike fit. The shorts are all high quality (at least expensive) Specialized and Pearl Izumi.

- Bike: 2013 Specialized Roubaix SL4 Expert Compact
- Saddle: Body Geometry Toupé RBX Comp
  [image: http://wheelworld.com/images/library/zoom/spec_toupe_rbx_comp_blk_13_z.jpg]

Here is a picture of the saddle and the clamp from above. I'm holding a level to show how the clamp extends past the saddle. I think that is what is causing the wear.

[image: Saddle and clamp]

Comment: The saddle looks quite sharp edged. I had to replace one similar shaped Specialized saddle with rounder one because it chafed at the same points your shorts have holes.

Comment: When seated. do the wear points in your pants match the corners of the saddle - where the D is, at the end of Specialized in the above stock photo ?

Comment: @criggle. Thanks. It's very similar. Same shape. I think I may have found the problem. When I'm on the saddle the wear points are directly over the clamp at the narrowest point. I'd say about 2 inches  back from the Troupe. I have my seat set pretty far back and the clamp is a little wider than the narrowest point of the saddle. I can even see where the paint has worn off the clamp. Not sure what to do now. I guess I need a saddle that is wider in the middle?

Comment: That saddle looks rubberised to me. Is it in real life?

Comment: @yothenberg: Do you have some strange clamp? Could you post a photo? I have a pretty narrow saddle too and I’ve only managed to rub off the paint/anodic coating over time. Since the clamp has no sharp edges I can’t imagine damaging my shorts with it.

Comment: Maybe see if you can get a post with more offset so the saddle doesn't have to be pushed back so far on the clamp?

Comment: @Michael Nothing strange about the clamp. It's  a standard clamp as far as I can tell. The stem is a Specialized Comp, FACT carbon. I've posted a photo that tries to show how much the clamp is extending past the point where my shorts wear. There are no real sharp edges but where the rails and the clamp meet there is a lip. I think that lip might be causing the wear. I think I'm going to have to change my seat post as Noah suggests or get a different saddle with more width at that point.

Comment: @yothenberg: Or file off the corner? It shouldn’t be load bearing.

Comment: One other thought occurs to me. The Body Geometry saddles are supposed to form to the rider. Perhaps the edges have just bent in over time? I have about 8k miles in this saddle?

Comment: It *might* indicate that you have your seat set just a bit too high.

Comment: @yothenberg Its been a month since you asked this question.  What have you done and how has it worked for you?  Do please add your own answer and mark as accepted, future searchers will thank you https://xkcd.com/979/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I ended up buying a new saddle, Fizik Arione, and it has completely solved the problem. As others have suggested a new seat pin with a clamp that is more offset would also have worked.

I think the wings of the saddle bent in over time because I haven't changed my seat position and I didn't get any rubbing for the first couple of years on the bike.

Answer (score 3):

It looks like your saddle is positioned quite far back, relative to the post.

Swapping the seatpost for one with more layback (offset) should allow you to keep the same saddle position relative to the bike but clamping the rails further back, where the saddle is wider.

Clamping further back on the rails may also reduce the risk of bending the rails.